# google oauth2 discovery return wrong token_endpoint

Tags: google-oauth

Here is the google oauth2 discovery url.
https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
And in the response, it looks like this

```
{
  "issuer": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "authorization_endpoint":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
  "token_endpoint": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo",
  "revocation_endpoint": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke",
  "jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs",
 ...
```

The `token_endpoint` in the google document here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#exchange-authorization-code said it should be `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`.

Maybe recently the `token_endpoint` is updated, but when I use `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` this one to exchange `token` with `code`., I will get an error response.

```
 { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }
```

And if I use `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` to do the same thing, everything is fine.

Is there anything changed in `google identify platform`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth endpoint has been updated a number of times over the last five years.  I normally follow the one i the discovery doc but your example shows that that is not always the best course of action all of the time.

I have never heard of google shutting down old endpoints i suggest you use the one that works.   As a side note i will contact Google to see if i can get some feed back as to why one call worked and the other didnt.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It works very well until this morning. So maybe something changed silently.

Comment: These end point changes have always been silent changes thats we never notice anything.   I have sent the mail off i will let  you know if i hear back.

Comment: Heard back he is doing some checking I will let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the great help!